# ASP.NET MVC Core, How render a value outside the model as some datatype like currency?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have some variables that are not part of the model attributes. for instance: my Model does have a function that generates a list of `decimal`.

```
List<decimal> CreateValues();
```

and I would like to render it as currency.

```
    @{
        var vals = Model.CreateValues();
    }

    @for (var i = 0; i < vals .Count ; i++)
    {
        Year @i: @val[i]
    }
```

this way it is rendered as decimal.

How can I tell to the render engine that those values should be rendered as currency? without using `.ToString("C")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason, why you shouldn't use `.ToString('C')`.

Another way would be `@Html.DisplayFor(e => val[i])` using the [Display Template](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html) `Decimal.cshtml`.

---

You could also create an Display Template for your whole List. But you need to refactor your ViewModel:

```
[UiHint("DecimalYearList")]
List<decimal> MyList { get; set; }
```

And in your `~Views/DisplayTemplates/DecimalYearList.cshtml`:

```
@model List<decimal>

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    Year @i: @Model[i].ToString("C")
}
```

And in your View, it is as simple as calling

```
@Html.DisplayFor(e => e.MyList)
```

Comment: is because `.ToString` is a known solution. I was wondering if is there any other way. For instance, angular uses pipes for formatting

Comment: Of course there are endless ways. I think above two are the correct ones. Of course you could even create a own wrapper object and overriding `ToString` method. Or you could write a custom HtmlHelper or TagHelper or ... and so on. @DanielSantos

Comment: Also take a look at the updated answer, if that is what you want @DanielSantos

Answer (score 0):

try `@string.Format("{0:C}", val);`